# ViewPager with tabs stackoverflow

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

i have a viewpager and i have four tabs.
i have these codes (just like google's tutorial) in my adapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

when i select a tab, the app crashes.
it seems like setCurrentItem and setSelectedNavigationItem are calling each other and it crashes the app.
am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Instead of doing all the loop stuff, just try to do:

viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

See if there's any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you your onTabSelected(.....), try doing this :

```
 @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition())
        }
```

Works for me. You can try it.